# Проблема с подключением к базе данных postgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

Я пытаюсь сделать 2 таблицы, используя `localhost` , как свой хост, но у меня выходит ошибка

```
  File "C:\Users\gelse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname='users', user='utsiye',password='48584858', host='localhost')
  File "C:\Users\gelse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Код:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname='users', user='utsiye',password='48584858', host='localhost')
connection2 = psycopg2.connect(dbname='shop', user='utsiye',password='48584858', host='localhost')
```

Пытался зайти в `службы`, чтобы перезапустить процесс, но там я его не нашел. Что это может быть? ОС: Windows 11

Comment: Не установлен или не запущен постгрес.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA я устанавливал psycopg2-binary, разве неверно?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA установил psycopg2 , та же ошибка

Comment: @CookieEater  psycopg2-binary библиотека для работы с БД. А сама БД работает?

Comment: @Alpensin в том то и проблема, раньше использовал SQLlite3, а нужно на хероку поставить, перешел на эту систему, а при запуске сразу вылетает ошибка, в логах виндовса ничего нет, даже autostart нет, как в других подобных вопросах.

Comment: По моему надо переустановить [postgres по документации](https://www.postgresql.org/download/)

Comment: @CookieEater sqlite3 это по сути просто файлик. Postgres совсем иначе устроен. Это отдельное приложение.

Comment: @Alpensin я понимаю, только это не отменяет того, что sqlite3 полегче будет, но хостингу это не интересно.

Comment: @Абдулазиз спасибо, та ошибка исчезла и теперь вылетела другая, им не подходит пароль, хотя я его скопировал и вставил с их же сайта.